# react hooks edit form does not select record to edit .the currentId is correct but record selected is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

i have i simple crud react hooks app with asp.net core webapi. the Courses component shows list but when click on link to edit a particular course the form shows with empty fields. the courses component jsx is as :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CourseList from "./CourseList" ;
import * as actions from "../_actions/courseActions";
import  NewCourseForm  from "./newCourseForm";
import CourseForm from "./CourseForm";
import { Grid, Paper, TableContainer, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, withStyles, ButtonGroup, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import  { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";



  const Courses =(props)=> {
     const[currentId,setCurrentId]=useState(0)
     const[flag,setFlag]=useState("list");




    const { addToast } = useToasts();
    // show componet object to show a particular component
      const showComp={list:"list",create:"create",edit:"edit"};


      useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchAllCourses();


        }, [])

        const onDelete = id => {
            if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?'))
            props.deleteCourse(id,()=>addToast("Deleted successfully", { appearance: 'info' }))
        }


   function onCreate(){
       setFlag("create")}






        function onEdit(id){
            setCurrentId(id);
            setFlag("edit");

        }


    console.log("flag in courses:"+ flag);
    console.log("currentid in courses:"+ currentId);


          switch(flag){
          case showComp.list:
         return( 
             <div>
            <Button onClick={()=>onCreate()}>Create Course </Button>

             <CourseList courseList={props.courseList}  {...({onDelete ,onEdit})} />
             </div>
             );




          case showComp.create:
          return( 
              <div>
              <NewCourseForm fresh={setFlag}   />

                  </div> 

                  );

                  case showComp.edit:
                    return(
                        <div>
                        <CourseForm courseList={props.courseList} {...({setFlag,currentId,setCurrentId}) } />
                       </div>
                    );

            default:
                return(
                <div>
             <CourseList courseList={props.courseList}  {...({onDelete ,onEdit})} />


             </div>
             );
                }






    }
    const mapStateToProps= state=>({
        courseList:state.course.list

    })
    const mapActionToProps={
        fetchAllCourses:actions.fetchAll,
        deleteCourse:actions.Delete

    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionToProps)(Courses);
```

in the above component i want to use the same CourseForm.jsx component for create and edit the record.when i click the link in CourseList component `onClick={() =>props.onEdit(record.courseId)}  /></Button>` the onEdit function of above component is called which `setCurrentId(id)` and `setFlag ("edit")` to launch the CourseForm component  with `{setflag,currentId ,setCurrentId}` and `CourseList` as props to select a particular course in courseform component. the CourseForm component is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, TextField, withStyles, FormControl, InputLabel, Select, MenuItem, Button, FormHelperText } from "@material-ui/core";
import {useForm} from "../_helpers";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../_actions";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        '& .MuiTextField-root': {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            minWidth: 230,
        }
    },
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 230,
    },
    smMargin: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
})

const initialFieldValues = {
    Title: '',
    Details: '',
    fee: '',

    Category: ''

}

const CourseForm = ({ classes, ...props }) => {



    //toast msg.
    const { addToast } = useToasts()

    //validate()
    //validate({Title:'jenny'})
    const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
        let temp = { ...errors }
        if ('Title' in fieldValues)
            temp.Title = fieldValues.Title ? "" : "This field is required."
        if ('Details' in fieldValues)
            temp.Details = fieldValues.Details ? "" : "This field is required."
        if ('Category' in fieldValues)
            temp.Category = fieldValues.Category ? "" : "This field is required."
        if ('fee' in fieldValues)
            temp.fee = fieldValues.fee ? "" : "fee is not valid."
        setErrors({
            ...temp
        })

        if (fieldValues == values)
            return Object.values(temp).every(x => x == "")
    }

    const {
        values,
        setValues,
        errors,
        setErrors,
        handleInputChange,
        resetForm
    } = useForm(initialFieldValues, validate, props.setCurrentId)

    //material-ui select label setting
    const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
    const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (validate()) {
            const onSuccess = () => {
                resetForm()
                addToast("Submitted successfully", { appearance: 'success' })
            }
            if (props.currentId == 0)
                props.createCourse(values, onSuccess)
            else
                props.updateCourse(props.currentId, values, onSuccess)
        }
    }

console.log("currentId in courseform:"+props.currentId)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.currentId != 0) {
            setValues({
                ...props.courseList.find(x => x.id == props.currentId)
            })
            setErrors({})
        }
    }, [props.currentId])

    return (
        <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Grid container>

                    <TextField
                        name="Title"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Title"
                        value={values.Title}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        {...(errors.Title && { error: true, helperText: errors.Title })}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        name="fee"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="fee"
                        value={values.fee}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        {...(errors.fee && { error: true, helperText: errors.fee })}
                    />
                    <FormControl variant="outlined"
                        className={classes.formControl}
                        {...(errors.Category && { error: true })}
                    >
                        <InputLabel ref={inputLabel}>Category</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            name="Category"
                            value={values.Category}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            labelWidth={labelWidth}
                        >
                            <MenuItem value="">Select Category</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="Math">Math</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="Computer">Computer</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="Science">Science</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="Physics">Physics</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="Other">Other</MenuItem>


                        </Select>
                        {errors.Category && <FormHelperText>{errors.Category}</FormHelperText>}
                    </FormControl>



                    <TextField
                        name="Details"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Details"
                        value={values.Details}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        {...(errors.Details && { error: true, helperText: errors.Details })}
                    />


                    <div>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            type="submit"
                            className={classes.smMargin}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            className={classes.smMargin}
                            onClick={resetForm}
                        >
                            Reset
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </Grid>

        </form>
    );
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    courseList: state.course.list
})

const mapActionToProps = {
    createCourse: actions.create,
    updateCourse: actions.update
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(withStyles(styles)(CourseForm));
```

the useform component is used to handle common tasks.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useForm = (initialFieldValues, validate) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues)
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        const fieldValue = { [name]: value }
        setValues({
            ...values,
            ...fieldValue
        })
        validate(fieldValue)
    }

    const resetForm = () => {
        setValues({
            ...initialFieldValues
        })
        setErrors({})

    }

    return {
        values,
        setValues,
        errors,
        setErrors,
        handleInputChange,
        resetForm
    };
}
```

the following error shows on console.

```
 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
    in input (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in ForwardRef(InputBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)) (created by ForwardRef(OutlinedInput))
    in ForwardRef(OutlinedInput) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(OutlinedInput)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(OutlinedInput)) (created by ForwardRef(TextField))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(FormControl))
    in ForwardRef(FormControl) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(FormControl)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(FormControl)) (created by ForwardRef(TextField))
    in ForwardRef(TextField) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField)) (created by CourseForm)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (created by CourseForm)
    in form (created by CourseForm)
    in CourseForm (created by WithStyles(CourseForm))
    in WithStyles(CourseForm) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Courses)
    in div (created by Courses)
    in Courses (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in Router (created by App)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Container))
    in ForwardRef(Container) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Container)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Container)) (created by App)
    in ToastProvider (created by App)
    in App
    in Provider
```

the console information shows that currentId in courseform is correct but value in setValues is not correct(i think undefined).

```
redux-logger.es.js:654  action FETCH_ALL @ 10:20:00.686
redux-logger.es.js:670  prev state Object
redux-logger.es.js:678  action     Object
redux-logger.es.js:694  next state Object
Courses.jsx:72 flag in courses:edit
Courses.jsx:73 currentid in courses:3112
CourseForm.jsx:122 currentId in courseform:3112
CourseForm.jsx:123 course in courseform:[object Object]
CourseForm.jsx:122 currentId in courseform:3112
CourseForm.jsx:123 course in courseform:[object Object]
```

i will be very thankful for your kind help. moreover if the structure to replace the components is wrong please guide.i am new to react.regards

Comment: ...... ... seems like you are passing the hooks from one component to others (`setCurrentId`, for example)... that is **NOT SUGGESTED**.  Maybe you should star refactoring that. Yo should pass event handlers (normal functions)

Comment: @CicheR        thanks for helping. can you please suggest how to   refactor setCurrentId  or any other workaround. regards

Answer (score 0):

i am sharing the code so that it might be helpful for others and save time.the main error i found out in the CourseForm.jsx component was in `setValues()` where id should replace with courseId .the courseform is given below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, TextField, withStyles, FormControl, InputLabel, Select, MenuItem, Button, FormHelperText } from "@material-ui/core";
import {useForm} from "../_helpers";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../_actions";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        '& .MuiTextField-root': {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            minWidth: 230,
        }
    },
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 230,
    },
    smMargin: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
})

const initialFieldValues = {
    courseTitle: '',
    details: '',

    category: '',
    fee: '' 

}

const CourseForm = ({ classes, ...props }) => {
    const[courseId,setCourseId]=useState(props.courseId)

        const dispatch=useDispatch();
    //toast msg.
    const { addToast } = useToasts()

    //validate()
    //validate({Title:'jenny'})
    const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
        let temp = { ...errors }
        if ('Title' in fieldValues)
            temp.Title = fieldValues.Title ? "" : "This field is required."
        if ('Details' in fieldValues)
            temp.Details = fieldValues.Details ? "" : "This field is required."
        if ('Category' in fieldValues)
            temp.Category = fieldValues.Category ? "" : "This field is required."
        if ('fee' in fieldValues)
            temp.fee = fieldValues.fee ? "" : "fee is not valid."
        setErrors({
            ...temp
        })

        if (fieldValues == values)
            return Object.values(temp).every(x => x == "")
    }

    const {
        values,
        setValues,
        errors,
        setErrors,
        handleInputChange,
        resetForm
    } = useForm(initialFieldValues, validate, courseId)

    //material-ui select label setting
    const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
    const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (validate()) {
            const onSuccess = () => {
                resetForm()
                addToast("Submitted successfully", { appearance: 'success' })
            }
            if (courseId == 0)
               dispatch(actions.create(values, onSuccess))
            else
                dispatch(actions.update(courseId, values, onSuccess))
        }

    }

console.log("courseId in courseform:"+courseId)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (courseId != 0) {
            setValues({
                ...props.courseList.find(x => x.courseId == courseId)
            })
            setErrors({})
        }
    }, [courseId])

    return (
        <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Grid container>

            <TextField
                        name="courseTitle"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Title"
                        value={values.courseTitle}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        {...(errors.courseTitle && { error: true, helperText: errors.courseTitle })}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        name="details"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="details"
                        value={values.details}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                        {...(errors.details && { error: true, helperText: errors.details })}
                    />
                    <FormControl variant="outlined"
                        className={classes.formControl}
                        {...(errors.category && { error: true })}
                    >
                        <InputLabel ref={inputLabel}>category</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            name="category"
                            value={values.category}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            labelWidth={labelWidth}
                        >
                            <MenuItem value="">Select category</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="science">science</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="Math">Math</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="Computer">Computer</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value="English">English</MenuItem>

                        </Select>
                        {errors.category && <FormHelperText>{errors.category}</FormHelperText>}
                    </FormControl>




                    <TextField
                        name="fee"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Fee"

                        value={values.fee}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}

                    />




                    <div>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            type="submit"
                            className={classes.smMargin}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            className={classes.smMargin}
                            onClick={resetForm}
                        >
                            Reset
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            className={classes.smMargin}
                            color="secondary"
                            onClick={()=>props.setFlag("list")}
                        >
                            Back to List
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </Grid>

        </form>
    );
}






export default (withStyles(styles)(CourseForm));
```

more over i shifted the presentational logic(`switch statement,showComp,ondelete,oncreate`) to `courseList.jsx`and used `courses.jsx` as controller component only.